# Outline of a sphere after perspective projection?

Tags: graphics, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm working on a 3D mapping application, and I've got to do some work with things like figuring out the visible region of a sphere (Earth) from a given point in space for things like clipping mapped regions and such.

Several things get easier if I can project the outline of Earth into screen space, clip polygons there, and then project back to the surface of the Earth (lat/lon), but I'm lost as to how to do that.

Is there a reasonable way to compute the outline of a sphere after perspective projection, and then a reasonable way to project things back onto the sphere?

Comment: It's probably easier to do the clipping in 3D. How do you represent the polygons?

Comment: Polygons would just be country shapes in lat/lon.   I need to clip the countries to the visible region of the globe so I can then project them into screen space and raster.  I'm doing this with software rather than OpenGL or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clip the polygons in 3D. The silhouette of the sphere - back-projected into 3D - will always be a circle on a plane. Perspective projection does not change that. Thus, you can clip all polygons at the plane.

Calculating the plane is not too hard. If you consider the sphere's center the origin, then the plane could be represented in normal form as:

```
dot(n, x) = d
```

`n` is the normal. This one is easy. It is just the unit direction vector from the sphere center to the observer.

`d` is the distance from the sphere center. This is a bit harder but not too hard. If `l` is the distance of the observer to the sphere center and `r` is the sphere radius, then

```
d = r^2 / l
```

This is the plane which you can use to clip your polygons in 3D. If you need the radius of the circle on it, you can use the following formula:

```
r_c = r / sqrt(1 - r^2/(l-d)^2)
```

Comment: I see, so you're saying clip the polygons against a plane in 3D rather than in 2D.  Is it correct to say that the intersection of that plane and the Earth would give me the visible horizon polygon?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The clipping would be a mixture of 2D/3D. For polygons that cross the plane, you will also have to take the circle into account (as the outline), which is then essentially 2D clipping..

Comment: OK I think that makes sense, I'll give coding it up a shot, thanks!

Comment: Also: any thoughts on how to apply your equations to the reference ellipsoid of the Earth, since it's not technically a sphere?

Comment: I'm not sure if the horizon of an ellipsoid lies on a plane. That would require some more thorough thoughts. A sufficient approximation might be to use the plane from above and an ellipse on it (rather than a circle) since earth is not squished much. But I'm not sure.

Comment: In your second formula there's a d^2 - what is that d? I presume it's different from the d we're calculating?

Comment: @MerseyViking It is the same `d`. Not sure why I wrote it like this, though. Updated with a simpler formula.

Comment: What is ```x```?

Answer (score 0):

Let us take a point on a sphere in spherical coordinates `(cos(u)sin(v),sin(u)sin(v),cos(v))` and an arbitrary projection center `(x,y,z)`.

We express that a projecting line is tangent to the sphere by the perpendicularity condition of the direction of the line and the vector from the origin of the sphere:

```
(x-cos(u)sin(v))cos(u)sin(v) + (y-sin(u)sinv))sin(u)sin(v) + (z-cos(v)) cos(v) = 0
```

This simplifies to

```
x cos(u)sin(v) + y sin(u)sin(v) + z cos(v) = 1
```

which is a curve in the longitude/latitude coordinates. You can solve `u` as a function of `v` or conversely.